# Avoiding html form input manipulation

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, google-api

I have several forms which contains data fetched from Google Directions Service (JS API), distance for example is especially important to me.

Sure, I know that I cant really prevent user from messing with the data in input fields, what I am asking is if there is some technique to make submitting manipulated form painful enough to stop people trying.

My hopes arent too high on this but I want to make sure before I get into some server-side solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are just getting data via the JS API and do not need any changes to those from user, how about sending the data to Server over AJAX calls as and when it is received perhaps with some your own simple encryption. This would certainly increase the number of requests but depending on the amount of data, it can work out for your usecase. Even if you would want to post some form data from the same page, it could be attached to a user's session on the server.

Please note that this is not fool-proof with firebug and the likes but gets more difficult for someone to play with the values.

Comment: Ok, so I get results from Google Directions, encrypt some of its data and pass it to server via AJAX and store it to the users session. This is good but how do I do this so it isnt so clear to user whats hapenning that he cant **easily** replicate that process with his values? Will JS obfuscation be enough? I know that term easily is relative but you know, comparing to making a change to hidden input value. :)

Comment: In my opinion, JS obfuscation would again make it harder to replicate. Unless the user is really determined to use a decompiler that can de-obfuscate the JS, this should involve a decent level of painstaking for a normal user. But as you might understand, a server side solution would be the way-to-go if you really want it to be fool-proof.

Comment: Sure, I will consider it. Your answer certainly shed some light to the issue, thank you.

Comment: Glad to help :) All the best !!

Answer (score 0):

try using hidden input fields:

```
<input type="hidden">
```

These get submitted to the server but are not visible to the user.

Comment: Sure but this doesn't stop them from changing the value via firebug or similar tool, does it?

Comment: you're sending data from a client machine, the client (or use on the client can ALWAYS make changes to what is being sent from his machine) the other alternative is to encrypt the user data, however you still have data on the client machine.